# Cannot compile against the mongo C++ driver in Fedora

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I have trouble compiling a code which uses mongodb-cxx driver. Everything works fine with C driver but not Cxx. I run Fedora 28 and have already installed following packages from Fedors's official repositories:

mongo-c-driver-1.9.5-1.fc28.x86_64
mongo-c-driver-devel-1.9.5-1.fc28.x86_64
mongo-c-driver-libs-1.9.5-1.fc28.x86_64
mongo-cxx-driver-1.1.2-13.fc28.x86_64
mongo-cxx-driver-devel-1.1.2-13.fc28.x86_64

The code I try to compile does not call any API function to connect to database, but as the first step, uses include files and namespaces needed to connect to a mongodb and run operations. The code I try to compile is:

```
#include <cstdint>                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mongo/db/json.h>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I try to compile the code as below:

> $ c++ --std=c++11 mongo-cxx.cc -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs
>   libmongocxx)
>
> Package libmongocxx was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libmongocxx.pc' to
>   the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable Package 'libmongocxx',
>   required by 'virtual:world', not found In file included from
>   /usr/include/mongo/db/json.h:20,
>                    from mongo-cxx.cc:4: /usr/include/mongo/bson/bsonobj.h:20:10: fatal error:
>   boost/noncopyable.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
>   
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

As said, I used Fedora's package manager to install monogdb's cxx driver and did not compile from the source. Is there any extra step that I need to do?

Thanks for your help,

D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix the old C++ driver and the new. The package that you have installed, `mongo-cxx-driver-devel-1.1.2-13.fc28.x86_64` is the end-of-life "legacy" C++ driver. It doesn't offer a pkg-config file.

Additionally, it appears that your code is attempting to include headers from both the old driver and the new mongocxx driver, which are completely separate projects.

Finally, you don't seem to have the required boost headers installed.

So, what you need to do is:

- Find out if you can get packages of the new C++ driver for fedora. If so, uninstall your legacy driver packages, install the new C++ driver packages, and remove the use of the headers that don't start with `bsoncxx` or `mongocxx`.
- If you can't get the new C++ driver, you need to use the legacy one, and you should stopusing the `bsoncxx` and `mongocxx` headers. You will need to install the boost development headers and libraries, and stop trying to invoke pkg-config, which is only used when finding the new C++ driver.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I removed mongo-cxx packages that I had installed. Since I had installed mongo-c-driver 1.9.5, therefore I had to checkout mongo-cxx-3.2.x which would be compatible with this version of C driver. I did so and build and installed and now it works fine. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Dan - Happy to hear you got it working. Hopefully someday fedora will start packaging the new driver.